# Can't provide `ChangeNotifier` passed via argument

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am testing some `Flutter` widgets that need to consume values from some providers. Since this task tends to be similar in most of my integration tests, I have created a function to streamline the usage:

```dart
Widget testableWidget(Widget widget, List<ChangeNotifier> notifiers) {
  final child = MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: widget,
    ),
  );

  return notifiers.isEmpty
      ? child
      : MultiProvider(
          providers: notifiers
              .map((notifier) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: notifier))
              .toList(),
          child: child,
        );
}
```

So that I can:

```
await tester.pumpWidget(testableWidget(someWidget, [MyNotifier()]));
```

This, however, throws:

`The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer<MyNotifier>(dirty): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<MyNotifier> above this Consumer<MyNotifier> Widget`.

This however works:

```
Widget testableWidget(Widget widget) {
  final child = MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: widget,
    ),
  );
  return notifiers.isEmpty
      ? child
      : MultiProvider(
          providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MyNotifier()),
          ],
          child: child,
        );
}
```

And, as per [the documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/provider):

> DON'T reuse an existing ChangeNotifier using the default constructor

This of course does not work:

```
Widget testableWidget(
    Widget widget, List<ChangeNotifier> notifiers) {
  final child = MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: widget,
    ),
  );
  return notifiers.isEmpty
      ? child
      : MultiProvider(
          providers: notifiers
              .map((notifier) => ChangeNotifierProvider(create:(_) => notifier))
              .toList(),
          child: child,
        );
}
```

I'm not getting what is happening here. Is the caller's notifier being disposed, somehow? Do test contexts have some particularity I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path.
From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html):

> DON'T use ChangeNotifierProvider.value to create your ChangeNotifier.

and

> DO create a new ChangeNotifier inside create.

so this is the constructor you want to use

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => new MyChangeNotifier(),
  child: ...
)
```

Most importantly, you will have to create a new instance inside the callback of the `create` parameter. And yes, it is important that the widget is built with the `BuildContext` from within this callback, not from the outside, so that it will be assigned the correct lifespan.

If you want to write some helper function for this, you could pass the constructors as a parameter like this.

```
typedef NotifierBuilder = ChangeNotifier Function(BuildContext context)

Widget testableWidget(Widget widget, List<NotifierBuilder> builders) {
  var providers = builders
    .map((builder) => ChangeNotifierProvider(create:(context) => builder(context)))
    .toList();

  final child = // some widget ...  

  return MultiProvider(
    providers: providers ,
    child: child
  );  
}
```

Comment: This does not work; throws the same error. Not sure why, though.